# AndroidアプリのaabファイルをPlay Consoleでアップロードできない

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-play-console

Android Studioで1つアプリを作成しリリースした後、今2つ目をPlay Consoleからアップしようとしています。Android Studioで作った拡張子.aabのファイルを、Play Consoleでアップロードしようとしても、以下のエラーがでてしまいます。

Android App Bundle が誤った鍵で署名されています。App Bundle を正しい署名鍵で署名して、もう一度お試しください。App Bundle はフィンガープリント「SHA1: xxxxx….
」の証明書で署名される必要がありますが、アップロードした App Bundle の署名に使われている証明書のフィンガープリントは「SHA1: yyy…
」です。

ここでいう正しい署名鍵のフィンガープリントは、作成中のアプリの「アップロード鍵の証明書」の「SHA-1 証明書のフィンガープリント」と同じでした。1つ目のアプリのものとは異なります。

Android Studioのどの画面のどの項目に何を入力し、どのボタンを押せばいいのか、詳しく教えていたどけるとありがたいです。

それとも、キーを再発行してもらえばできるものなのでしょうか？その場合一つめのアプリのキーも変わってしまうのでしょうか？

Androidデベロッパーサイトやそのほかいろいろ調べてはみたのですが、鍵のしくみが根本的に理解できてないようです。

試したこと

Play Consoleで削除し、Android Studioのファイルも一度削除し、aabファイル作成前のバックアップに保存していたファイルから再度aabファイルを作成しアップロードし直しました。

Android StudioでBuild>Clean Projectを実行後、再度新しいaabファイルを作ることもやってみました。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決ですが、開発したファイルをバックアップでaabファイルを新規で作り直し、Play Consoleを新規作成し、そこにアップロードしたところ、無事できました。
もっと真っ当な方法はあると思いますが一応解決したのでご参考になれば。
アプリのアップデートでは使えませんが。